# if statement in mathematica

Tags: summation, conditional

I have a summation but I would like to put a condition like if j < q then assign 0, otherwise just perform the sum. But, I could not find how to explain this to mathematica.

```
Remove["Global`*"];
Needs["Developer`"];
$Assumptions = i ∈ Integers && j ∈ Integers && k ∈ Integers && q ∈ Integers;

a[j_, q_] := If[0 <= q <= j, 0];
a[j_, q_] := (2 q - 1 - j)! q!/((2 q - 1)! j! (q - j)!);

d[n_, q_] := I^n *Sum[(-1)^j*a[j, q]*a[n - j, q], {j, 0, n}];

FullSimplify[d[2 q, q]]
```

The output I should get is this `((q-1)! / (2q-1)!)^2` (which is easy to obtain by hand)

What mathematica gives me is very different.

Comment: Edit your post and add the code for the sum.

Comment: try `Clear[a];a[j_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ]:=..`

Comment: You may have a lingering definition of `a`.  Evaluate `ClearAll[a, d]` then run your code.

Comment: does `q` have a value? This will not work for symbolic `q`

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I have tried to improve it a bit, but still I am not getting what I should.

Comment: You might consider using `Piecewise[]`: `a[j_, q_] := 
 Piecewise[{{0, 0 <= q <= j}}, (2 q - 1 - j)! q!/((2 q - 1)! j! (q - j)!)]`

Comment: Note that your definition implies that d[2q,q] = 0. (Since either 2q -j >=q or j>=q). This suggest that your problem is not with Mathematica syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote your definitions the second definition of `a[j_, q_]` would overwrite the first. If you want to create cases of a function with special values you can use the `Condition` pattern (`/;`) in the LHS of the definition.

```
  a[j_, q_]/;0 <= q <= j := 0;
  a[j_, q_] := (2 q - 1 - j)! q!/((2 q - 1)! j! (q - j)!);
```

This should give the correct result.

Comment: I tried, it seems that the result is equal to what I need to get, but I do not understand why instead of a simple expression it gives the following, which is sort of meaningles 

       (-1)^q \sum _{j=0}^{2 q} \frac{(-1)^j (j-1)! (q!)^2 (-j+2 q-1)!}{j! ((2 q-1)!)^2 (j-q)! (q-j)! (2 q-j)!}

Comment: @mment finally figured out, thanks